# Junit Console Launcher .. support for tag expressions

Tags: junit, junit5

My junit-console-launcher command vaguely resembles,

java -jar ./junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp . -c pkg.Class1 -c pkg1.Class2 -t A --details=verbose

I do this because I need to send in my classes in a certain order. I needed help in using tag expressions which is documented here,
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions

-t 'A & B' does not seems to be recognized by junit console launcher. I need to select tests which are tagged both A and B. Is this supported? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher

> `-t, --include-tag=TAG`
>
> Provide a tag or tag expression to include only tests whose tags match. When this option is repeated, all patterns will be combined using OR semantics.

This indicates, that "tag expression" are supported.

You just need to convince your OS/shell command to pass the `A&B` string as a single argument without the quotes.

*Note: you also need to pass a class name filter pattern that matches your test classes, something like `--include-classname .*Class?` Or wait until 1.7.0-M2 is released: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2259*

Comment: I have had quite a good run with junitconsolelauncher. Thank you for that. Been successful in sending selected classes  using the -c option. My question is related to the -t/-T option .. which is not accepting logical operators like & | !. Is this supported? If I use the command 


java -jar ./junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp . -c pkg.Class1 -c pkg1.Class2 -t A&B --details=verbose

Its exits with error code 1, saying & is invalid.

Comment: Thanks @sbrannen @sormuras!! That resolved my problem. Just for reference the command looks like ,
`java -jar ./junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp . -c pkg.Class1 -c pkg1.Class2 -t A&B --details=verbose`

It includes selected classes having both A and B tags.